How can I use vim.api from an external Lua script?
I want a different program to communicate with neovim. Based on documentation,
this should be done via vim.api. I found examples on how to do this via
Java or Python. I want to use a Lua script.
If I run lua test.lua, where test.lua is:
vim.print('test')

I get the error:
lua: open-external.lua:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'vim')
stack traceback:    open-external.lua:1: in main chunk  [C]: in ?

If I use:
require("vim").print('test')

then
lua: open-external.lua:1: module 'vim' not found:   no field
package.preload['vim']  no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/vim.lua'  no
file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/vim/init.lua'
    [...]

What is the correct way to use vim.api from an external Lua script? In the
final result, I want NeoMutt to send commands to a
running instance of neovim. In particular, I want to reload the buffer after
NeoMutt changed a tempfile. Do I need to add the vim module to some Lua path?
If so, where is it located and how to I add it to the Lua path? Or should I use
an entirely different approach?

At least with Vim, I'd expect this communication to be done either using --remote-expr to communicate to a Vim server or via :help channel to communicate between Vim and a running process.
I think neovim similarly has a remote plugin API, but it's not the same as using the internal vim module: what you're looking at is provided to the Lua running inside neovim. In the neovim documentation, I think these are called "API clients"? You might also be looking for :help api-rpc?
It seems that you want to connect an RPC client from Lua to neovim—that's a question of programming more than of neovim, I think.

thank you. indeed, i was looking at the :help api-rpc where it reads 'Nvim exposes a powerful API that can be used by plugins and external processes via RPC, Lua and Vimscript (eval-api).' however, i cannot figure out, how to do it via lua, or where to find documentation on this. in fact, i cannot run any vim command within lua nor load the vim module, as described above.

From reading subsequent sections, I think the answer is "You connect with an RPC client and send requests through the client" @grbll

yes, and there are even examples on how to do it in ruby and python. and i tried the python version and it worked, i also found the command line tool nvr which allows for command line access to the 'sever'. however, i can't figure out how to do it with lua code run by an external interpreter.

@grbll Again, I think the answer is "You connect with an RPC client and send requests through the client." That's not something I know how to do in Lua, though I imagine googling will get you somewhere.
